# Where can I find historical data on arrival and departure times of a particular flight?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, airlines

Where can I find historical data on flights, specifically Delta international flights?

I need to find out about cancellations, diversions and any other flight data pertaining on particular route at a given time.  This source has to be official and stand up to legal scrutiny.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The two best sources for this type of data are [FlightAware](http://flightaware.com) and [Flight Stats](http://www.flightstats.com/). Although these sites both get data from the FAA, I don't know that either would be considered "official".

The nearest to official source would be the FAA data available at https://transtats.bts.gov/ONTIME/. However, this data is always several months behind (eg, they currently have up to June 2019 as of August 2019), and not as easy to search for specific flights as either of the above two sites.

For both Flight Stats and FlightAware, you'll need to create an account and buy a subscription, unless the data you want is only a few days old.

Comment: I came here to say flightstats, def agree with @Doc's answer above.

Comment: Thanks, I got the info I needed after signing up for a free account.

Comment: Please be aware of the fact, that for instance flightrights does not allow to use their data for any passenger claims, see https://developer.flightstats.com/about/terms_for_paid_accounts

Comment: The URL has changed to https://www.transtats.bts.gov/Fields.asp?Table_ID=236

Comment: FlightStats historical flight data are now paid subscription only.

Comment: What about non-FAA sources?

Comment: @domen some airlines provide on-time, cancellation data for specific routes in their apps.  Other than governmental aviation regulatory bodies, you would probably have to inquire of the airlines directly.

Comment: The airlines are a bit hesitant to do that. They will often have a conflict of interest, since passengers want that data for compensation claims.

Comment: Flightradar24 is an other source. You see also the track, so you may have better estimate is arrival time were correct. But AFAIK historical data is paid only (different options)