# Historic flight altitude data?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, flight-data

I am working on a project for school, and I am trying to find past flight data concerning the altitude of the aircraft over the duration of the flight. This will then be used to identify contrails in a Landsat image.

I can find past departures and arrivals easy enough, and Flight Aware keeps a record of altitude for flights from the past 7 days, but I'm looking for flights possibly back to a year in the past. Is it possible to get this information? Of course, the source has to be official and stand up to legal scrutiny.

Comment: Downvoters - please explain with a comment. This is a new user and no comment downvotes don't help anyone.

Comment: Possible downvotes because it seems to be outside the scope of http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Why altitude and not flight paths? I'm also trying to decide if you should ask on [gis.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Have you contacted FlightAware to see if they're willing to provide you the data? If you make a very specific and limited request, they might waive any fees for an educational use.

Comment: And weird that you used the same wording for your last sentence as @miles-leacy in [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/historical-flight-data?rq=1).

Comment: Official ... legal scrutiny ... for a school project?

Comment: I think your question is better suited for [aviation.se](http://aviation.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Chrismas007 quite possibly, but then they should help to put it on topic, rather than just blank voting :(  Or they could vote to close if off topic (probably more important)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about aviation data, not travel