# Flight EZY7153 on 9/3/2017 Liverpool to Arrecife

Tags: easyjet

I am trying to get historical flight data relating to the specific flight.
EZY 7153 from Liverpool (LPL) to Arrecife (ACE)
The airline states the flight was 2 Hours and 57 Minutes late.
I believe that it was over 3Hours
The flight stats / log may help ?

Comment: Also of possible interest is *[Historical flight data outside of the USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44263)*. I am not sure whether the regulation governs arrival at the gate or arrival at the airport, which may explain the discrepancy. Note that FlightStats.com explicitly forbids the use of their data for making customer service claims, and competing services likely have similar clauses in their terms and conditions, and they do not want to get caught in between airlines and angry customers.

Comment: You could always contact the CAA and ask them, they are likely to have the most accurate information (and if there was a dispute their data would be the proof of whether it was under or over the 3 hour limit). It won't cost you anything to ask if you do it online.