# Old Flight Schedules (pre 1991)

Tags: air-travel, usa

I am looking for historical airport schedules from the US and Canada from after WWII. For example, I would really like to see a flight schedule (or schedules) from New York from around 1948. Any ideas where I might find this data either on the internet or in an old publication?

This is not like the question [Where can I find historical data on arrival and departure times of a particular flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/historical-flight-data) because that question was about relatively recent flights. I am aware that I could get data from flightstats.com for the last ten years or so. What I want is flight schedules that are from before 1991.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Historical flight data](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/historical-flight-data)

Comment: I would ask this question at [Opendata.SE].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about contemporary travel planning.