# Spirit Airline Flight Delay

Tags: air-travel, delays, spirit-airlines

On July 14, 2018 our Spirit Airline Flight #263 was delayed for over 4 hours. We were flying from BWI to Seattle, WA.
The flight was supposed to leave at 7:20 AM. I would like to know what time the flight actually took off.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please see *[Where can I find historical data on arrival and departure times of a particular flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/where-can-i-find-historical-data-on-arrival-and-departure-times-of-a-particular)*

Comment: Note that _taking off late_ is completely irrelevant for any compensation or complaints. _Arriving Late_ is relevant; that is what you should look for.

Answer (score 2):

[According to FlightAware](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/NKS263/history/20180714/1120Z/KBWI/KSEA), Spirit 263 on Jury 14 left the gate at 11:10AM, 3 hours and 50 minutes late and arrived in Seattle at 1:34PM, 3 hours and 26 minutes late (flight schedules are generally padded somewhat, so not every minute of a departure delay is always an arrival delay).

You can certainly complain to Spirit (not that they're known for being customer friendly), but be aware that [the US has no flight delay compensation law](https://www.transportation.gov/individuals/aviation-consumer-protection/flight-delays-cancellations), so there is likely nothing they're legally obligated to provide in this case.