# Where to find flights statuses by airport for a given day?

Tags: airports, cancellations, flight-status, kbp

On November 23, 2018 I had a flight from KRK (Krakow, Poland) to KBP (Kiev, Ukraine) via Ryanair, flight no. FR 6640. The flight was canceled due to bad weather conditions on KBP airport. Now, I'd like to submit for a flight compensation basing on EU261 and I'm looking for more information on the flight statuses that day/time at given airport, i.e. KBP.

How to find a historical and free of charge data of flight statuses per airport? I was looking for such data but ended up with paid options.

---

**EDIT:** This is not a duplicate of [Where can I find historical data on arrival and departure times of a particular flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/where-can-i-find-historical-data-on-arrival-and-departure-times-of-a-particular) The mentioned question asks about particular flight and that one is about airport. Also, sources given in the accepted answer provides paid historical data. The 3rd link is a non-existing page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately **I don't believe any such global free database exists**: FlightAware, FlightStats and OAG all charge for data that's more than a few days old, and copyright the data provided by their APIs to ensure nobody else can either.  There are various national sources, but I'm also not aware of any that would cover Poland or Ukraine.

If you're unwilling to pay for this, there are a number of professional claim services that will look up your flight and claim compensation on your behalf, but the cut they take is likely larger than what you would pay for just the flight data.

*Source*: It's hard to prove a negative, but I'm the primary maintainer of [OpenFlights](https://openflights.org), one of the main repositories of [free flight data on the Internet](https://openflights.org/data.html), and I'm fairly sure I would know if one existed!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @jpatokal. From these three (FlightAware, FlightStats and OAG), is there any that you have used and can recommend? And, is there a 100% certainty that these sources will contain data I'm looking for?

Comment: FlightStats has the friendliest UI: https://www.flightstats.com/company/flightstats-announces-self-service-historical-flight-status-data/