# I need to find the Find flight no from Palma Majorca to Norwich on 24/05/2022

Tags: flight-search-engines

I need to find the Tui flight no leaving Palma Majorca at 9.35am to Norwich on 24/05/2022 it was delayed 3-4 hours

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find historical data on arrival and departure times of a particular flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/where-can-i-find-historical-data-on-arrival-and-departure-times-of-a-particular)

Answer (score 4):

Should be the flight number BY5249.

[image: BY5249]