# Flight LH947 Frankfurt

Tags: connecting-flights, lufthansa, missed-flights, frankfurt, late-arrival

Please can you tell me what time did LH947 arrive in Frankfurt from Manchester UK on Wednesday 8th March as I missed my connecting flight at the airport

Comment: What time was your connecting flight? Were you self-transferring or were both flights on one booking?

Comment: @Traveller:  [It appears](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179986/departing-flight-et707) that they were trying to connect to Ethiopian Airlines 707.  According to [FlightRadar24](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/et707) the other flight departed at 9:55 PM.  It seems like they should have had plenty of time so long as the flights were booked on the same ticket (and Lufthansa & Ethiopian do have a code-sharing agreement.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find historical data on arrival and departure times of a particular flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/where-can-i-find-historical-data-on-arrival-and-departure-times-of-a-particular)

Answer (score 8):

After 18 seconds of research*, I found that flight LH947 arrived in FRA [5 mins earlier than scheduled](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/lh947#2f73eb38).
[image]

EDIT 1: *As noticed by Willeke, I forgot to explain how to check it by yourself for the future:

1. Open your browser (whatever you use to surf the web, it might be Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE or whatever, you can find a list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers))
2. Type in the flight number and search it by pressing go or return on your keyboard.
3. Open the first or second results listed.
4. Read.

EDIT 2: As noticed by jcaron, times can differ by few minutes depending on many factors as landing time can be recorded following different criteria (touching time, time at gate, doors opening, I'm sure jcaron won't miss the chance to be more precise on this) but will be sostantially the same; if your flight arrived on time as your case, you'll never find hours of difference on some sites...

Comment: Note that FR24 gives landing time, while the scheduled time is at the gate. [Flightaware](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/DLH947/history/20230308/1805Z/EGCC/EDDF) gives a gate arrival time of 20:38.