# When did flight ET707 depart on March 8th?

Tags: missed-flights

Please could someone give me the gate closure time at gate B43 flight number ET707 and the flight departure time on 8th March 2023 as I missed this flight to late arrival from Manchester and distance to gate from arrival in terminal

Comment: Your incoming flight was only 3 minutes late, that shouldn’t have made any difference. Were both flights on a single ticket? What row were you in on the first flight? did you advise staff of the short connection? Did you go straight from one gate to the other?

Answer (score 1):

On 3/8 ET707 departed 9.33pm from B47, i.e. two minutes early (see https://flightaware.com/live/flight/ETH707/history/20230308/2045Z/EDDF/HAAB)  This is normal variation, so the flight was "on time" for all practical purposes.

The gate closing time isn't documented anywhere but it's almost always printed on your boarding pass. I suggest taking a look there. For most US airlines it's 15 minutes before departure (9.20pm in your case) but many other airlines keep it more flexible depending on gate and terminal conditions.

What was your incoming ? Eurowings 947 arrived 8:38pm (on time)  and Lufthansa 939 arrived at 6:20pm (20 minutes late, but plenty of time for connecting).I don't see any "late arrival from Manchester".

If this was booked as a single itinerary with EW947/ET707, that was indeed a tight connection but both flights appear to have been on time and the connections seems doable. Frankfurt is large but that's all in Terminal 1. Since the UK is not in Schengen, you would not have to clear passport control either.

What gate did your Manchester flight arrive at, what time were you out of the plane and What time did you arrive at gate B43 ?

Comment: Ethiopian’s advertised boarding gate closing time is 30 minutes before departure. I believe the incoming flight (LH947) arrived at B gates, so it should have been a short distance, unless one has to go through security in this case (don’t know the rules in FRA). But if this was all on a single ticket, I would be surprised if they hadn’t waited or even had someone to help passengers to speed up the connection.

Comment: Pretty certain the OP would have had to go through security to get to the connecting flight gate, that’s always been the case for me anyway when transferring in FRA from MAN. They do occasionally change the gate, I almost got caught out by sitting happily at the gate# shown on the screens when my inbound flight arrived, only to realise it had been changed at some point