# Past flight deviation information

Tags: diversion

How do I find the detailed information for a flight deviation of a past flight from United Airlines?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find historical data on arrival and departure times of a particular flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/where-can-i-find-historical-data-on-arrival-and-departure-times-of-a-particular)